# How to simulate stdin in shell script and check the stdout answer

Tags: linux, shell, stdout, stdin

I'm currently doing the overthewire exercises and I'm stuck at one point, or more precisely I would like to solve a lvl doing differently from what I could find on the web.

I have to pass a password to a nc command with a pin code, and according to that I have an answer written on stdout (telling if it's right or wrong).
The pass is made with a fix first part, and a pin code between 0000 and 9999.

The fact is that by doing this with cmd line, it's like : `echo "my pass" "4-digits pin code" | nc localhost 30002`
Then I have the answer depending whether my pin is correct or not.

What I would like to do as a script (maybe I'm totally wrong since this very first step) :
I check with the man that nc could accept to launch a script with the '-e' option.
So I decided to build a script to do the following :

I call the localhost on the port : `nc localhost 30002 -e "myScript"`
Within my script, I would like to, recursively, echo the combination of the pass and a 4 digit pin to the stdin, in order for me to make the server answering right or wrong.
Then I check the stdout (where I suppose I can read the right or wrong answer from the server), to define if I find the right pincode.

Just to say, I only know the wrong answer that I can have, no idea what the right answer can be.

Here is the code I tried to build (don't flame plz, I'm new :) ):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                          
 
pwd=UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ
 
#nc localhost 30002
 
for i in {0001..9999}
do
    cat <<< "$pwd $i" #Here I try to simulate a input on stdin
    cat 1> /tmp/Frack/password
        if ( grep -o "Wrong" { "$(</dev/fd/3)"; } 3<&1 ) #Here I try to check if there's an answer from the server, and if it contains the word "Wrong"
    then
        continue
    else
        echo "pass trouvé : $i" > /tmp/Frack/password #If I found the right pin code, I write it within this file (on which I gave the right access to be able to write on it).
        break
    fi
  
 done
```

I add an example of what I'm supposed to read as an answer from my call to the server with a wrong pin code : "I am the pincode checker for user bandit25. Please enter the password for user bandit24 and the secret pincode on a single line, separated by a space.
Wrong! Please enter the correct pincode. Try again."

Comment: `I check with the man that nc could accept to launch a script with the '-e' option` There are (sadly) multiple versions of netcat. The BSD netcat doesn't support -e. Are you sure you are using GNU netcat? `Here is the code I tried to build` Does it work? `$(</dev/fd/3)` did you open `fd/3` somewhere?

Comment: `would like to, recursively,` why not iteratively? You are in your script iterating over each possible combination. Why recursive? `Then I check the stdout` You have to describe how the communication looks like. You pass a _single line_ of _ascii printable data_ consisting of _two columns_ separated by space to the remote server. What is the format of the answer you get from the server?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers, for recursive, I'm not english so just a mistake but a quick look at my code show that I'm looping (so making it iteratively you're right). For my code, it's not working unfortunately and the file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
#!/bin/bash
# note stdout is connected to remote end
# note stdin reads from remote end
for i in {0001..9999}; do
    # hacky hack to output to controlling terminal
    echo "testing $i" > /dev/tty
    # output the password to stdout
    printf "%s\n" "password $i"
    # read one line from stdin
    if ! IFS= read -r line; then
         echo "error" > /dev/tty
         exit 1
    fi
    # if the word "wrong" case insensitive is missing from readed line
    if ! grep -i -q 'wrong' <<<"$line"; then
        # then we are finished
        echo "I'm in" > /dev/tty
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

then I can:

```
$ nc -e /tmp/1.sh localhost 10000
testing 0001
testing 0002
testing 0003
testing 0004
I'm in
< --- snip -------- >
$ nc -v -v -l localhost -p 10000 <<<$' wrong \n wrong \n wrong \n ok'
Listening on any address 10000 (ndmp)
Connection from 127.0.0.1:39152
password 0001
password 0002
password 0003
password 0004
read(net): Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but not working for me. It's only doing the first loop and I guess it's reading what's on the screen and not what's sent by the nc call. I add an answer that the nc call can send in my first post.

Comment: I add that after further testing, it seems that I only have the first part of the server answer, but not the Wrong sentence (so your if is not working), I try again modifying your if.